# sequelize belongstomany disable same id

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Been digging in the docs for a while, couldn't find this option.

Scenerio:

```
User.belongsToMany(User, {
  as: 'following',
  through: 'follows',
  foreignKey: 'follower_id',
  otherKey: 'followed_id',
  // disableSameId: true <--- the kind of option I'm looking for
});
```

in this scenerio, the behavior I'm looking for is to disallow a user to follow himself.

currently my implementation is obvious, checking for `id1 !== id2` before making the request, but still wondering about this possible root shortcut

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution I am happy about:

search led me [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1264#issuecomment-298023561) which had me creating a model for this `rel-table`

Using a custom `validator` did the trick.

```
return sequelize.define('Follows',
{},
{
  timestamps: true,
  paranoid: false,
  underscored: true,
  freezeTableName: true,
  tableName: 'follows',
  validate: {
    IdsShouldNotMatch() {
      compare(this, 'Cannot follow yourself');
    }
  }
});


// model_helpers/compare.js
module.exports = (that, error) => {
  let condition = Object.values(that.dataValues)
    .map(v => Number(v))
    .reduce((a, b) => a - b);
  if (!condition) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};
```